# Linux/PHP connect to PowerShell

Tags: bash, powershell, ssh, office365

In order to execute some commands via powershell for Office365 i'm looking for a way to connect from my linux machine, using PHP or bash, to Powershell.

So far i have only seen IIS + PHP way of executing commands via exec but not from linux.

Comment: sshd for windows, Isn't that working for you?

Comment: NO, because i need to connect to Office365 Powershell where i don't have ability to install anything etc.. it's just some remote Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. It works with IIS + PHP because it is on Windows server, and the Windows server supports PowerShell, but Linux doesn't support that.

As to connect to Office 365, a remote PowerShell runspace is created on the Office 365 server side to run the PowerShell script, but on your local computer, it still needs a client to communicate with this remote runspace. On Windows, it has this client, but I doubt there's an equivalent on Linux.

Comment: I don't expect Windows developer or sys admin to know this. THis question is more for linux guys that had similar needs.